# Full guide on configuring NIS/NFS on OS X 10.7?

Tags: macos, nfs, directory-utility

I am trying to setup OS X 10.7 Lion to work as an a NIS/NFS client but without too much success so far.

### Existing configuration that works on Ubuntu

```
cat /etc/yp.conf
domain uk.example.com server 10.80.16.129

cat /etc/auto.master 
/usr/groups yp:auto.groups --timeout=3600
/home yp:auto.home --timeout=3600
/nistest yp:auto.misc --timeout=3600
/misc yp:auto.misc --timeout=3600

>ypwhich
nis2.uk.example.com
```

### Configuration on OS X (that does not work yet)

I tried to add the NIS domain using `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Unlock > Login Options > Join... > Open Directory Utility...`  (yes Apple did a great job on making this as hard as possible to access).

There edit the `NIS` record and add the NIS domain `uk.example.com` (not the same as  DNS domain) and the IP address of this NIS domain `10.80.16.129` and obviously checked the `Use NIS for authentication`.

I rebooted but this did not help. Still, interesting on login screen there was a tooltip saying that network login is unavailable.

I logged in with an admin account, logged out but the situation did not change.

### Debugging

```
>ypwhich
nis2.uk.example.com
```

cat /var/log/opendirectory.log

```
2012-06-27 10:46:50.575 BST - opendirectoryd (build 172.13) launched...
2012-06-27 10:46:50.577 BST - Logging level limit changed to 'error'
2012-06-27 10:46:50.600 BST - Initialize trigger support
2012-06-27 10:46:50.610 BST - Registered node with name '/Active Directory' as hidden
2012-06-27 10:46:50.611 BST - Registered node with name '/Configure' as hidden
2012-06-27 10:46:50.612 BST - Discovered configuration for node name '/Contacts' at path '/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations//Contacts.plist'
2012-06-27 10:46:50.612 BST - Registered node with name '/Contacts'
2012-06-27 10:46:50.614 BST - Registered node with name '/LDAPv3' as hidden
2012-06-27 10:46:50.617 BST - Registered node with name '/Local' as hidden
2012-06-27 10:46:50.619 BST - Registered node with name '/NIS' as hidden
2012-06-27 10:46:50.620 BST - Discovered configuration for node name '/Search' at path '/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations//Search.plist'
2012-06-27 10:46:50.620 BST - Registered node with name '/Search'
2012-06-27 10:46:50.626 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/legacy.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:50.632 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/search.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.636 BST - '/Search' has registered, loading additional services
2012-06-27 10:46:51.636 BST - Initialize augmentation support
2012-06-27 10:46:51.642 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/SystemCache.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.647 BST - Successfully registered for Kernel identity service requests
2012-06-27 10:46:51.653 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/PlistFile.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.656 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/FDESupport.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.707 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/ConfigurationProfiles.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.708 BST - Registered subnode with name '/Local/Default'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.712 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/nis.bundle'
2012-06-27 10:46:51.713 BST - Registered subnode with name '/NIS/uk.example.com'
2012-06-27 10:47:21.743 BST - 239.839.841.843 - Client: automount, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
2012-06-27 10:47:21.743 BST - 239.839.841.843, Node: /NIS/uk.example.com, Module: nis - could not determine map for rectype 'mounts' attribute 'byname'
2012-06-27 11:10:30.994 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/configure.bundle'
2012-06-27 11:10:30.996 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/keychain.bundle'
2012-06-27 11:10:31.010 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/ldap.bundle'
2012-06-27 11:10:31.017 BST - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/ActiveDirectory.bundle'
2012-06-27 11:11:06.745 BST - 1801.3397 - Client: Directory Utili, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
2012-06-27 11:11:06.745 BST - 1801.3397, Node: /NIS/uk.example.com, Module: nis - could not determine map for rectype 'mounts' attribute 'byname'
2012-06-27 11:15:42.254 BST - 1801.4096 - Client: Directory Utili, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
2012-06-27 11:15:42.254 BST - 1801.4096, Node: /NIS/uk.example.com, Module: nis - could not determine map for rectype 'mounts' attribute 'byname'
```

Comment: I think osx is not suitable for network use ( lion, mount lion) as Finder has a huge bug un refresh folder/ file with nfs